# HDMI cable compatibility?

Tags: hdmi, compatibility, cable

I have a PC connected to a screen with an HDMI cable.

The screen works (with a different HDMI cable) and the cable works (with a different screen)

Is there any interesting compatibility issues that I should be aware of?

Details:
Standard Windows 10 desktop with 1920x1080 resolution
The BIOS POST screens don't show up
The cables are 1.5m long
Brands: UNITEK and LINDY
It's as if the screen doesn't know that it is connected to a device

Comment: [HDMI is versioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Versions) version numbers must all be of a given minimum spec, GPU, cable & screen. Without more detail we can't guess what your min spec needs to be, but later cables work with earlier hardware; yet not the other way round.

Comment: Can you please specify the model of the screen, specs of both HDMI cables and probably your graphics card? (thanks Tetsujin :D)

Comment: @CaldeiraG how can you get the specs of a random HDMI cable?